# How to create a Future of a map of a different type

Tags: scala

I am using com.twitter.util.Future, scala 2.11.11

I have this piece of code that I'm trying to convert into a Future[Map[Long, String]]

```
val simpleMap: Map[Long, Int] = Map(1L -> 2, 2L -> 4)
val keyToNewFutureMap = Future.collect(simpleMap.map {
    case (key, value) =>
      val newFuture = getAFutureFromValue(value)

      key -> newFuture
  }.toSeq.toMap
)

val keyToFutureMap = Map(1L -> Future.value(1))
val futureMap = Future.collect(keyToFutureMap) // converts into a 
Future[Map[Long, Int]]

Future.collect(Seq(futureMap, keyToNewFutureMap)) // Stuck here
```

I'm stuck here. I wanted to use the returned maps from both Futures and generate a new map. The new map will contain unique keys that appear in both `futureMap` and `keyToNewFutureMap`.

`keyToFutureMap` is given in the form of a `Map[Long, Future[Option[Int]]]`, which is why I used a `collect` to turn it into a `Future[Map[Long, Int]]`

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: You want a `Future` `Map` of `oldKey -> result of getAFutureFromValue(value)`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want this:

```
val newFutureMap = Future.traverse(simpleMap) {
  case (key, value) =>
    getAFutureFromValue(value).map(key -> _)
}.map(_.toMap)
```